# Hashtag in url issue

Tags: asp.net, query-string, sqldatasource

I have a querystring parameter that populates another page and the problem happens when the parameter starts with a hashtag #

Ex:
mysitepage/Details?param=#456

Of course this happens because hashtags in url ends the request. The problem is that these are ids from the database and cant be changed. Instead of using a querystring, is there any work around for this that someone can inform me of.

**Edit1-**

I realized I was encoding the whole url wheere the problem was. Now I am only doing the parameter part, but it seems to be making the parameter static instead of dynamic now:

example :

```
String.Format("mysite.com?param="+Server.UrlEncode({0}), Eval("param"))
```

basically it encodes the 0 in curly braces and not the actual evaluated value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should checkout [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332871%28VS.71%29.aspx)

It will encode # to %23& and of course you can decode it back with `UrlDecode()`

Comment: How am I suppose to get the querystring on the new page because Request.Querystring wont do it for hashtags

Comment: @Jake whoever put's the param into the querystring has to encode the value first before it gets put in.

Comment: I fixed the problem but thx to you I got on the right track. I ended up just doing it in javascript since I had to wait for data to be evaulated before encoding

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode and decode the parameter. With ASP.NET MVC, I'm using `Url.Encode()` and `Url.Decode()` for this.

`#456` encoded is `%23456`

It looks like you can use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` and `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` in ASP.NET.